# The concept of being too obsessed with honour

Tags: single-word-requests, concept

I'm looking for a word that refers to excessive or extreme obsession with fairness, discipline, chivalry, and respect. Note that this is the concept, rather than a person who embraces it.

An equivalent for honesty would be candor, for safety: cowardice.

Comment: I like "quixotic"

Comment: @J.Taylor I was just researching that as an answer.  Like minds!

Comment: @ lbf   I think it might be worth an answer from you, I will pass the honor

Comment: "punctilious" would work, but only in a context where fairness, discipline, chivalry, and respect are considered correct behaviour.

Comment: @J.Taylor - I don't think "quixotic" is the same thing.

Comment: It seems to me that what is called for is your personal attempt at a poetic description.

Comment: Those four words (five with honor) are pretty orthogonal to me. The extremes for each one I think of as: fairness -> disinterestedness; discipline->rule-bound,displinarian; chivalry->deferential or uxorious; respect (and honor)-> feudal or face-saving or non-judgmental

Comment: .Righteousness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quixotic**

quix·ot·ic

kwikˈsädik/

adjective: quixotic ( from Merriam-Webster)

> foolishly impractical especially in the pursuit of ideals; especially
>   : marked by rash lofty romantic ideas or extravagantly chivalrous
>   action. [quixotic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quixotic)

And here's a short piece on Don Quixote and his mistaking windmills for giants. [Don Quixote](https://www.shmoop.com/don-quixote/chivalry-symbol.html)

Comment: Just so you know, it is not enough to just link to the "Google Dictionary" entry. Please cite [Google's source](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/). See [this meta post](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7053/191178) for details.

Comment: This is an answer that fits, thank you. I assume the concept would be called 'Quixoticism'?

Comment: This covers the part about an extreme of chivalry, but 'quixotic' means so much more (especially the first part about extreme and foolish pursuits. That is, for a samurai lord who is excessively loyal to the shogun, it would be strange and misleading to call them 'quixotic' (because you'd also think that person foolish)

Answer (score 1):

Honour as a concept can have a few different opposites. It also has slightly differing definitions depending on context, and you blew through a few of them in your post. I think it's difficult to label all of honour's opposites with one word/concept. One interpretation of honour in excess, from the perspective of reputation and meriting respect due to the content of their character, could be [Vanity](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vanity).

> 1 : inflated pride in oneself or one's appearance : conceit
>
> 2 : something that is [vain](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vain), empty, or valueless
>
> Vain: having or showing undue or excessive pride in one's appearance or achievements

So if vain is what describes a person who overly pursues a good reputation, vanity is the base concept of that description. One can of course achieve a good reputation by being chivalrous, fair, respectful, etc... I think that this does not fit if one is talking about honour in terms of *integrity*, as the opposite of that is not vanity but dishonesty. Therefore a person with integrity in excess would be rude or discourteous.

Answer (score 0):

**an obsessive sense of justice**

I believe this phrase was coined by Susan Conners, author of *The Tourette Syndrome and OCD Checklist*.

I'm sorry it's more than one word.

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't really what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think "authoritarian" might be closer to what you are looking for; someone who believes in following the rule structure above all else.

But it's hard to say, since your terms are kind of ambiguous.  For instance, a poor old women trips in the street and bumps into a rich lord.  Does the obsession with "respect" means that the woman would be berated for disturbing her social better, or that the woman is comforted and aided, out of compassion for her age and frailty?